# Position a button inside a div

Tags: html, css, position

As you can see in my [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/r86xy8h1/1/), I have a div and three buttons. I would like the buttons to be placed at `right: 85%` (so that you get what I mean), without me having to use `position: absolute`.

I also tried this:

```
.button {
    float: right;
}
```

.. but the buttons fall out off the `div`.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `position: absolute`?

Comment: Because I would have to hardcode where every button should lie, based on my screen only @iamnotmaynard

Comment: Yeah, I think I see what you're going for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r86xy8h1/4/).

I've added a `div` to hold your three button divs. You can update the margin right to have it more to the left.

```
div.button-holder div:last-child{  
    margin-right: 10px;   
}
```

Comment: Nice try. The buttons are nicely on the x axis, but not on the y. What I mean is that I want them inside the header!

Comment: Ok the buttons are positioned nice. I would like them to be a bit less to the right though. I mean now Delete touches the right border of the header. I would like it a little to the left, like 10px for example, so that it will not touch! Moreover, the text is also moved (it shouldn't). +1 for the try though.

Comment: There you go. [This one](https://jsfiddle.net/r86xy8h1/4/) should be good. Mybad, I didn't know what you wanted exactly.

Comment: Then it was my bad, because I wasn't clear enough when posting the question. It's perfect, update the answer please.

Answer (score 1):

Change Markup and add class:

```
<div class="header_div">
   foo

   <div class='btns'>
      <button class="button">New</button>
   </div>
   <div  class='btns'>
      <button class="button">Load</button>
   </div>
   <div  class='btns'>
      <button class="button">Delete</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

*Instead Of..*

```
.button {
    float: right;
}
```

*Try This...*

```
.btns {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: John that's almost perfect. However, I would like the button not to reach at the end of the screen. So now, it;s like it has `right: 100%` and I would like it to be about 90%.

Comment: You can add margin .btns:first-child {
    margin-right: 60px;
}

Comment: Thanks for the advice John!